# Query for creating a auto increment column in SQL Server CE, C#

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce, auto-increment

What is the query in SQL Server CE to create a column that is auto-increment?

Tried with `IDENTITY(1,1), PRIMARY KEY` .. No luck yet :(

Please guide me, thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you show the entire query (and eventually what error did you get)? Also, why the C# tag?

Comment: Which **VERSION** of SQL Server CE are you using?? 2005? 3.5? 4.0 ??

Comment: You could just look it up http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174639(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174639%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE MyCustomers 
    (
      CustID int IDENTITY (100,1) PRIMARY KEY
     ,CompanyName nvarchar (50)
    )
```

I think your issue is the ',' after the identity clause - remove it and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried with

```
IDENTITY(1,1), PRIMARY KEY
```

try dropping the comma:

```
IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Also, please note that:

- a table can have at most one identity column
- you can specify `PRIMARY KEY` on a column the first time you create the table. If you are doing an `ALTER TABLE [...] ADD COLUMN`, this is invalid